# How to do barrier in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, barrier

I do push notifications. If there is no data in the database, they downloaded before display.  I did a time interval using `Grand Central Dispatch`, but it is not right because for example if the user is a weak Internet application falls.

How delay with barrier of GCD the display of the data before download data?

This code with time interval:

```
if equal == false {
    let url = "https://****.**/json/post/\(data)"
    self.download.getLastestNews(url)
}


let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
    let newsCategory = self.realm.objects(News.self).filter("newsID == \(self.id)")
    vc.titleText = (newsCategory.first?.newsTitle)!
    vc.fullText = (newsCategory.first?.newsFullText)!
    vc.imageLink = (newsCategory.first?.newsImage)!

if let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController {
   tabBarController.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

**Platform iOS 9.*, iOS 3**

Answer (score 0):

Delaying the queue won't always work because as you said, sometimes Internet connection is too slow and there might be no data received, so the program may fail with error. While downloading anything from Internet, check for completion handling methods. Inside them use the code you gave in DispatchQueue closure.